# Plot a graphics object stored in .mat file with new Matlab Graphics Engine

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

UPDATE # 1:

So, it seems that the following approach is a bit simpler than using the handle2struct and struct2handle functions in Matlab. Basically, I just save figure handles to an array and then save the array using the savefig function.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:0.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)+eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

% 1: Save 4 figures to an array called 'H': 

for i = 1 : 4
    H(i) = figure('Visible','Off');
    surf(X,Y,Z);
end
savefig(H,'fig_container.fig','compact');
close(H)
clearvars

% 2: Open 4 figures:

figs = openfig('fig_container.fig','visible');

for i = 1 : 4
    H(i) = figs(i);
end
```

However, I seem to lose some functionality by ***not*** using the h2s/s2h functions--specifically, I'm forced to use the openfig function to load the saved fig file ... this is bad news if I've saved hundreds or even thousands (millions?) of figures to a single array within a fig file because, by using the openfig function, I load ***it all***. This was the principle benefit, it seems, of using the h2s/s2h functions ... I could save the structs to a mat file and then use the matfile function to load each struct individually (unless I'm not understanding the proper workings of the matfile function). The following code shows how I used the matfile functionality:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:0.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)+eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

fig_container = cell(4,1);
for i = 1 : 4
    fig = surf(X,Y,Z);
    figure_in = struct2cell(handle2struct(gcf));
    fig_container{i,1} = figure_in;
    clearvars figure_in
end
clearvars -except fig_container
close all

save fig_container.mat fig_container -v7.3;

figure_final = figure;
name_cell = {'type','handle','properties','children','special'};
for i = 1 : size(fig_container,1)
    matObj = matfile('fig_container.mat');
    single_cell = matObj.fig_container(i,1);
    lime = single_cell{1,1};
    loadedData = cell2struct(lime,name_cell,1);
    figure_sub = subplot(2,2,i);
    figure_out = struct2handle(loadedData,0,'convert');
    figure_out_children = get(get(figure_out,'children'),'children');
    set(figure_out_children,'parent',figure_sub);
    set(figure_out_children,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none');
    r1 = randi(91)-1;
    r2 = randi(91)-1;
    set(gca,'View',[r1 r2]);
    close(figure_out);
    clearvars figure_out figure_sub
end
clearvars -except fig_container figure_final
% close all
```

I ***could*** continue to use this method, but there has to be a way to load parts of a ***fig*** file variable without loading the entire variable ... I much prefer the simplicity of the savefig/openfig approach, but I can't find a way to grab only one saved figure at a time.

Any ideas?

Justin

---

For historical purposes, here's my first post:

I'm new to the use of figs as objects in Matlab 2015a (a feature introduced in Matlab 2014b). I'd like to save multiple `fig` files to a `mat` file then retrieve them later for plotting. Because 2014b and later are relatively new,I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in a normal web search. The code below stores 4 figures called `figure_in_1`, `figure_in_2`, `figure_in_3`, and `figure_in_4`, each having a value of `1x1 Surface` and a class of `matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface`:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:0.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)+eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

for i = 1 : 4
    cmd = horzcat('figure_in_',num2str(i),' = surf(X,Y,Z)'); eval(cmd);
    if exist('fig_container.mat','file')
        save('fig_container.mat',horzcat('figure_in_',num2str(i)),'-append');
    else
        save('fig_container.mat',horzcat('figure_in_',num2str(i)));
    end
end
clearvars -except fig_container
close all
```

What I'd like to do is grab these graphics objects and plot them. So, the question is: How do I grab and plot an already-stored Matlab graphics object?

Justin :)

Comment: I think you are overwritting the object every time you save it because it has the same name

Comment: Thanks, @Naveh :) I just updated the post ... any ideas how I might be able to take one of the graphics objects and plot it?

Comment: @Justin please consider accepting the answer to indicate the system, that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure my problem is resolved yet. I'm playing around with two different versions of MATLAB now to see what works best. I guess I'm still looking for a close-out to the question at the end of my section entitled UPDATE 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some things which are considered bad practice in your code, especially [**the use of `eval`**](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval), in your case to create variable names out of strings. The better option is to use structs with string type fieldnames.

Here is, how I would do it:

```
%// data
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:0.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)+eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

%// struct with surfaces, this is where all surface graphics will be
surfaces= struct;

%// loop creating all figures and storing it
%// create new figure every iteration, plot the surface, save its handle with a dynamic
%// name into the surfaces struct
for ii = 1 : 4
    figure
    surfaces.(['figure_in_',num2str(ii)]) = surf(X,Y,Z);
    %// save to matfile
    save('fig_container.mat','surfaces','-append')
end

clear
close all

load('fig_container.mat')

%// loop for displaying 
for ii = 1 : 4
   %// create new figure and axes
   figure; axes;
   %// get surface froms truct (this line can be abolished and used directly below)
   sur = surfaces.(['figure_in_',num2str(ii)]);
   %// assign parent axes object for displaying  
   set(sur,'parent',gca)
end
```

If you ***really*** don't want to store the surfaces in a struct in your matfile, **use a struct anyway, but** use this command for storing:

```
save('fig_container.mat','-struct', 'surfaces', fieldname,'-append')
```

Your figure container will now not contain the struct `surfaces`, it will contain all handles as single variables:

```
>> whos
  Name             Size            Bytes  Class                                          
  figure_in_1      1x1               112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface
  figure_in_2      1x1               112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface
  figure_in_3      1x1               112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface
  figure_in_4      1x1               112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface
```

And you can plot a single surface just by:

```
figure; axes;
set(figure_in_1,'parent',gca)
```

or even simpler

```
set(figure_in_1,'parent',axes) %// but no new figure window will be opened, 
                               %// if desired call figure before
```

or in a `subplot`

```
figure;
subplot(121)
set(figure_in_1,'parent',gca)
subplot(122)
set(figure_in_2,'parent',gca)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @thewaywewalk. I'd been using handle2struct and struct2handle previously, but my impression was that I could bypass use of structures altogether by leveraging the object-ness of figures in recent versions of Matlab. I will examine your code tomorrow and see how it stacks up against what I've already done with handle2struct and vice versa. Does your method preserve view angle information, etc.? Sorry for needing to get back to you tomorrow, but it's late here :)

Comment: no it doesn't. Because these information are part of the axes-handle and not of the plot-handle. So just use the same approach and store the axes-handles.